# jQuery trigger event attached on children first then its parent's event

Tags: javascript, jquery

Event attached on the children triggers first than it's parent and I think its default behaviour, is there anyway the it can work in alternate way?

Here is an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/dhiru/rb99n7uh/4/

```
<div class="parent">Parent
    <div class="children">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="result">Result here</div>

$('.parent').on('click', function () {
    $('.result').append('<p>Parent Clicked</p>');
});
$('.children').on('click', function () {
    $('.result').append('<p>Child Clicked</p>');
});
```

In a condition I want to trigger the event attached in its parent not in its child's event even clicked on children. I know it can be fixed by making some adjustments in children element, but I don't want to make changes in the event attached in its children as it be being attached by 3rd party plugin.

Comment: `event.stopPropagation();` ?

Comment: So you want only parent event to be triggered, even if child is clicked right?

Comment: Yes, I want the parent is triggered first then its child.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not prioritize the parent event to execute first than the element event. If to events are attached to same object, then they would execute in same order.

But this is not the case in your condition. the first event is attached to parent element and another event to element itself. In this case the first event that will execute first is the place where the event started which is child element in your case. And you cannot override this behaviour.

However you can prevent event bubling( to stop parent event propagation to child) using `stopPropagation` in child element event:

```
$('.children').on('click', function (e) {
 e.stopPropagation()
 $('.result').append('<p>Child Clicked</p>');
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n33t0nnn/)**

Comment: What you have done is made some adjustments in children element, this is what I don't want.

Comment: @Dhiru no... you can add a new handler... not in the plugin's handler

Comment: @Dhiru: you can simply write another handler with stopPropagation in it.

Comment: @Milind, If I write stopPropagation in parent till than the event attached in its children is already run

Comment: No no....you should not be adding that part in parent event. also you can not trigger the parent event first. check the updated answetr

Answer (score 1):

Its because of event bubling. You have to use e.stopPropagation() method to stop this.

```
$('.parent').on('click', function () {
    $('.result').append('<p>Parent Clicked</p>');
});
$('.children').on('click', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('.result').append('<p>Child Clicked</p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want to make changes in the child handler, one option is to check whether the event's target is within the children element

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).closest('.children').length) {
    $('.result').append('<p>Parent Clicked</p>');
  }
});
$('.children').on('click', function() {
  $('.result').append('<p>Child Clicked</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">Parent
  <div class="children">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="result">Result here</div>
```

---

Another option is to use event delegation and stop the event propagation

```js
$('.parent').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.result').append('<p>Parent Clicked</p>');
});
$('.parent').on('click', '.children', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});

//handler in the plugin
$('.children').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.result').append('<p>Child Clicked</p>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">Parent
  <div class="children">Child</div>
</div>
<div class="result">Result here</div>
```